Swift Charts: overflowResolution on the X-axis only works on one side

I am working on a project that displays the number of steps users have taken in the last 15 days on a chart. I implemented the chart selection behavior introduced in iOS 17, which shows a RuleMark with an annotation for the selected value.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var stepCountRecords = [StepCount]()
    @State private var selectedDate: Date?
    
    @State private var fitToChart: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(stepCountRecords) { record in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Date", record.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Count", record.steps)
                )
                
                if let selectedDate {
                    RuleMark(x: .value("Selected", selectedDate, unit: .day))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondarySystemFill).opacity(0.3))
                        .annotation(
                            position: .top,
                            overflowResolution: AnnotationOverflowResolution(x: horizontalAnnotationOverflowResolutionStrategy, y: .disabled)
                        ) {
                            Text(selectedDate.formatted())
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                        }
                }
            }
            .chartXSelection(value: $selectedDate)
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            
            Toggle(isOn: $fitToChart) {
                Text("Fit to chart")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            generateRecords()
        }
    }
    
    private var horizontalAnnotationOverflowResolutionStrategy: AnnotationOverflowResolution.Strategy {
        if fitToChart {
            return .fit(to: .chart)
        } else {
            return .automatic
        }
    }

}

The peculiar thing is that I can now scroll way past the dates in my data source. I am not sure why I am allowed to do that. I do not want this behavior. And I cannot limit it. To address this issue, I’m trying to use the fit-to-chart annotation overflow resolution option on the horizontal axis, but it only works for the left side of the chart. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?
Here’s a small sample project for your reference.

I'm asking to reopen the question as an original question. The odd scrolling appears to be resolved by restricting selectedDate to the data's dates rather than being wide open as a general Date type. I don't think the problem is directly related to the display of the annotation. Closers correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Thank you for your comment. I did try an intermediate binding that restricts date selection to the range we have in the underlying data. And it seems to work, but it does introduce another weird quirk. The date selection is persistent, even when the user removes the finger. All in all, I think that this is a bug in the framework since restricting the range is a hack.

I will post a working solution with the tap working as expected should this be reopened. Your Xcode project was appreciated.
